# Raising a propertychanged event without adding a private variable

Tags: c#

I have a property which looks like this.

```
public int NumberOfElephants { get; set; }
```

this property is in an observablecollection and it has to notify another property that it has changed.

how would i do the following

```
public int NumberOfElephants { get; set { OnPropertyChanged("totalAnimals"); }
```

without the code needing to be like this

```
private int _numberOfElephants;
public int NumberOfElephants { 
    get { 
        return _numberOfElephants; 
    } 

    set { 
        _numberOfElephants = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("totalAnimals"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't. You can't.

Automatically implemented propertieS *only* work when the property is trivial - when no code is needed for the get/set beyond "return the variable's value" or "set the variable's value". You can make it shorter with reformatting, of course... I'd write that as:

```
private int numberOfElephants;
public int NumberOfElephants {
    get { return numberOfElephants; }

    set {
        _numberOfElephants = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("totalAnimals"); 
    } 
}
```

Actually, I'd use "opening brace on a line on its own" for the start of the set and the start of the property, but I've kept your favoured style for those. But having "single expression `get`/`set` implementations" on a single line can make classes with lots of properties much cleaner.

Comment: is there no way to "Extend" the getters and setters?

Comment: @JosephLeBrech: Only by writing it out in full. There's nothing in between.

Comment: that's a shame, even magic like `[Property("totalAnimals")]` would be nice, I'm asking this question because I have a further 10 properties to do that same thing to.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech as per my answer, you can get tools that do it via IL weaving

Comment: i'm having a look at this now, but I need to notify `totalAnimals` that it would need to change also. do i have to specifically do that?

Comment: you can use `DynamicObject` and override `TrySetMember`, that can be the "magic" Joseph wants.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Jon's answer, you can get tools that will do this via IL weaving, such as  [NotifyPropertyWeaver](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), also available as a tool through the [VS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3)

For your sample, you should be able to have something like the following, according to their [doco on Attributes](http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/wiki/Attributes):

```
[NotifyProperty(AlsoNotifyFor = new[] { "TotalAnimals" })]
public int NumberOfElephants { get; set; }

public int TotalAnimals { get; set; }
```

However, based on the example below from their site it might not be required depending on the implementation of `TotalAnimals`:

> **Your Code**
>
> ```
> public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {
>     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
>
>     public string GivenNames { get; set; }
>     public string FamilyName { get; set; }
>
>     public string FullName
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> **What gets compiled**
>
> ```
> public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {
>
>     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
>
>     string givenNames;
>     public string GivenNames
>     {
>         get { return givenNames; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value != givenNames)
>             {
>                 givenNames = value;
>                 OnPropertyChanged("GivenNames");
>                 OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     string familyName;
>     public string FamilyName
>     {
>         get { return familyName; }
>         set 
>         {
>             if (value != familyName)
>             {
>                 familyName = value;
>                 OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
>                 OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     public string FullName
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
>     {
>         var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
>         if (propertyChanged != null)
>         {
>             propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: but how would I use notifypropertyweaver to tell the property `totalAnimals` that this will have changed too

Comment: I haven't actually used it, but reading the doco it appears to be possible (either by convention or with explicit attributes). I'll update the answer

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the answer by @jeffora

Using [NotifyPropertyWeaver](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) you could write this

```
public class Animals: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int NumberOfElephants { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMonkeys { get; set; }

    public int TotalAnimals
    {
        get
        {
            return NumberOfElephants + NumberOfMonkeys;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And this would be compiled

```
public class Animals : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int numberOfElephants;
    int numberOfMonkeys;

    public int NumberOfElephants
    {
        get { return numberOfElephants; }
        set
        {
            numberOfElephants = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalAnimals");
            OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfElephants");
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfMonkeys
    {
        get { return numberOfMonkeys; }
        set
        {
            numberOfMonkeys = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalAnimals");
            OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfMonkeys");
        }
    }


    public int TotalAnimals
    {
        get { return NumberOfElephants + NumberOfMonkeys; }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With tool like PostSharp you can weave the property to create the boiler plate code code. More, you don't have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, PostSharp can do it for you.

See this [blog post](http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/inotifypropertychanged-with-postsharp/).

Answer (score -1):

I would use this in C#6

```
private int numberOfElephants;
public int NumberOfElephants {
    get => numberOfElephants; 

    set {
        _numberOfElephants = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged(); 
    } 
}


private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This needs

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```