# Property Getters and Setters when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for a lot of classes, and each of these classes have lots and lots of properties. I have been following this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for how to implement INofifyPropertyChanged, but their instructions don't seem to be practical in cases where a class has many many properties.

Currently most of my properties use the short hand:

```
public DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }
```

But the documentation says that i need to add the following to each setter method:

```
// Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
OnPropertyChanged("DateClosed");
```

This means that I then need to declare a body for the get method and declare private variables to handle the actual getting and setting of properties. Like this:

```
private DateTime? _dateOfIncident = null;
public DateTime? DateClosed
{
    get { return _dateOfIncident; }
    set
    {
        _dateOfIncident= value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("DateClosed");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Regex search and replace, T4 templates, code snippets, what have you tried? I mean you're not the first to run into this. :)

Comment: Did you comment on the right question? I dont know what Regex, and T4 Templates have to do with this lol. I haven't really tried anything because It doesnt seem like calling OnPropertyChanged() anywhere else besides a setter makes sense.. but at the same time I don't want to create all those private properties just for the getters and setters

Comment: @user3653277 Yes, CodeCaster commented on the right question. T4 templates allow C# code to be generated, and the generated code to be compiled by Visual Studio. A regex is a possible simple way of generating the C# code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raising a propertychanged event without adding a private variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847057/raising-a-propertychanged-event-without-adding-a-private-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few classes can easily be changed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But since you state you have *a lot* of classes with a lot of properties, it's a real burden to get this done manually or even with templates.

What you really need is a tool that does it for you, so I present you [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) and it's NotifyPropertyChanged plugin. What Fody does is weave some extra code in between your code at compile time. The only thing you have to do is add a single attribute on the classes you want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the rest is done for you.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{        
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to find a workaround here. Auto-properties, as you're using them now, are really just a compiler shorthand that get's converted to full properties with a backing field eventually anyway (at least, as I understand it).

The use of INPC is a routine that's sorta separate and apart from the duty of a normal property. It's notifying subscribers (usually, your view XAML) that the property in question has changed or is changing.

**tl;dr** -- you're not going to get around having to rewrite autoproperties to full properties with backing fields. But toolkits like [MVVMLight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) have some great Visual Studio code snippets to make this relatively fast. Eventually you can even do this:

```
private string _someString;
public string SomeString
{
    get { return _someString;}
    set 
    {
            //Set returns bool, so you can trigger other logic on it! 
            Set(() => SomeString, ref _someString, value);
    }
}
```

This gives you some neat features:

- Strong naming (unlike the magic string in your example)
- `Set` only triggers INPC event if the value is different
- `Set` returns boolean so you can perform more action if the value changed

MVVMLight is nice in that you don't have to use all its features, or even implement MVVM pattern. It just has a lot of nice 'tools' you can leverage.

Comment: The `() => SomeString` part can be removed when you use the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in that `Set` method - it causes the compiler to insert the name of the calling property for you.

Comment: I don't see how is that new property better of standard full property. You so much hate repeated `OnPropertyChanged()` (with `CallerMemberName` ofc) to trade it for that syntax?

Comment: The simplest answer to his question is: You need to actually implement INPC in your properties if you want to use it. But my answer notes that not only do you get some additional benefits implementing it in *this* particular way, but MVVMLigth includes codesnippets that make implementing many properties a snap.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of patterns to do it, or you can buy a tool [like PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) that will do it for you.

For example, here is one method of doing it:

```
public abstract class BaseNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _valueStore = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName]string property = null)
    {
        object value = null;
        if (!_valueStore.TryGetValue(property, out value))
            return default(T);
        return (T)value;
    }

    protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName]string property = null)
    {
        _valueStore[property] = value;
        OnPropertyChangedInternal(property);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = null)
    {
        OnPropertyChangedInternal(property);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChangedInternal(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Which you then inherit from your classes:

```
public class PlainOldObject : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return Get<int>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }
}
```

Which takes care of the backing store and everything for you. You may want to add logic to only call the `OnPropertyChangedInternal` if the property actually changed (compare references or value), but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Dictionary lookup instead of full property? Code snippets will do way better (save you from typing 2 lines of code which you save).

Comment: @Sinatr I said it was one way, not the optimal way, but even with snippets, and some performance issues aside, this does have the advantage of having all the logic to trigger the notification in one place, reducing duplication and maintenance.

Comment: *"Not the optimal way"* and *"some performance issues"* are the thing. And as for *"having all the logic to trigger the notification in one place"* all logic is in `OnPropertyChanged` already. It's over-engineering imho, unless you have to do something more complex (can't think of anything suitable) than just triggering event.

Comment: For what it's worth, WPF dependency property essentially take the same route as described here (minus the generic type-safety).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Observable Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff653818.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) class. Instead of creating a `DateTime` property, you'd create an `ObservableObject<DateTime>` and you would just bind to `DateClosed.Value`.

Comment: I think this answer should point out that that class is not a part of the BCL, but comes with [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx).